# Mathematical way to represent a image kernel?

Tags: image-processing

How can I represent the calculation in this image mathematically?

[image]

For example, with the discrete convolution (and Fourier Transform?),

$$(f * g)[n]\ \stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=}\ \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty f[m]\, g[n - m]$$

Comment: Not your exact question, but similar: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/7847/35

Comment: What is your question? The operation in the movie is a convolution with a particular mask. You already state how this is typically written. The mask is your $g$.

Comment: This operation is already $\mathcal{O}(N)$, where $N$ is the number of pixels (i.e. cells); its complexity can't be improved, because every pixel must be visited at least once. The FFT -- or any other Poisson solver -- could come in if you wanted to invert the operation, as the stencil is simply the classic $5$-point stencil for $-\Delta$.

Answer (score 1):

From the computational point of view, each element of the final matrix (resulting image) is equal to a operation between the around elements in the initial matrix (input image) and the respective elements of the kernel, so:

$ final_{i,j} = \\
 initial_{r(i-1),r(j-1)} OP kernel_{1,1} + initial_{r(i),r(j-1)} OP kernel_{2,1} + initial_{r(i+1),r(j-1)} OP kernel_{3,1} + \\
 initial_{r(i-1),r(j)} OP kernel_{1,2} + initial_{r(i),r(j)} OP kernel_{2,2} + initial_{r(i+1),r(j)} OP kernel_{3,2} + \\
 initial_{r(i-1),r(j+1)} OP kernel_{1,3} + initial_{r(i),r(j+1)} OP kernel_{2,3} + initial_{r(i+1),r(j+1)} OP kernel_{3,3} \\
$

where the $r(x)$ represents the integer division between the x and the matrix side.